# Non Turing-Recognizable from symmetric difference

Tags: computability

I have a question about how you would find a example of a non Turing-recognizable language from the symmetric difference of two Turing-recognizable languages. I believe this is possible, but I am having problems coming up with a example in my head. Does anyone have any hints, or ideas about how to think about this?

Comment: Hint: one of the languages consists of all strings.

Comment: I was thinking of it in terms of sets, so the Turing-recognizable set is a subset of non Turing-recognizable. But if this is the case, then no symmetric difference could contain a non Turing-recognizable language. The only cases I could think of is if you take cases like if the symmetric difference was the empty set...

Comment: Another hint: A language is Turing-recognizable but not Turing-decidable if...

Comment: @YuvalFilmus A language is Turing-recognizable but not Turing-decidable if it loops on some inputs and neither accepts or rejects, right?

Comment: So I am thinking that the first language, `A`, will consist of all strings and is decidable and recognizable. The second language, `B`, will be recognizable but not decidable. When you take the symmetric difference of the 2 you are left with a subset of all strings. If a input, `w`, existed in `B` then it cannot be recognized by the symmetric difference, but the string `ww` could exist, if this is the case the TM would not be recognizable???

Comment: A language doesn't "loop". A Turing machine could loop on a specific instance. A language is Turing-decidable is there is a Turing machine that always stops and answers YES or NO correctly. It is Turing-recognizable if there exists a Turing machine that either outputs YES or never terminates (there are other, equivalent definitions).

Comment: You are on the right track, but you need a small lemma to work the details out. What do you know about the (semi-)decidability of the complement of an undecidable but semi-decidable language?

Answer (score 1):

(Converting the comment hints and guidance into an answer)

If you take $A$ to consist of all strings, $A=\Sigma^*$, then $A$ is decidable and recognizable. 
Then, we will take the second language, $B$, to be recognizable but not decidable.

Their symmetric difference will give us (by definition) $\overline B \triangleq \Sigma^* \setminus B$.

Now, let's get concrete. The halting problem, $HP$, is a recognizable non-decidable language. If we take $A=\Sigma^*$ and $B=HP$, then their symmetric difference is $\overline {HP}$. The last step is to show that $\overline {HP}$ is not-recognizable (but this is a very well known fact that $\overline{HP}\in coRE$ and not-recognizable, since if it was recognizable, then $HP$ would have become *decidable*, since for any input we would have a machine that says "yes" if it is the language, and another machine that says "no" if it is not).